# Is it possible to create a search form to query a list with Choice columns?

Tags: search, choice-field

I have a list with 'Choice' (checkbox) columns and would like to know if it's possible to create a search form where the user can select the check boxes they would like to see results for.

For example, if the list contains a 'Choice' column with the choices Yellow, Green, Blue, and Black; the user would use the Search form to select the check boxes Yellow and Green and receive all of the list items that had those boxes checked in that column when they were added to the list.

The search form would also allow the user to set criteria for other columns as well but it seems that the 'Choice' column would be the most complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by setting up a search result page with your Choice column as a refiner.

You can find the information on how to achieve this here but basically it will come down to:

1. Perform a Full Crawl.
2. Map the Crawled Property (ows_ColumnName) to a Managed Property.
3. Create a Search Result page with the query pointing to the list in question.
4. Add the new Managed Property as a refiner with a new display template for a multi value selection.

How to setup refiners: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/10/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

How to setup Multi Value refiners: https://www.eliostruyf.com/part-6-create-multi-value-search-refiner-control/

Hope that helps.